# Set console output color from a pattern in a xml with Logback

Tags: xml, scala

I'm using Scala Logback classic for logging and I want to send some part of the premade message in color.

If I'm using println I simply type:

```
println(Console.RED + "Message goes in red" + Console.RESET + ", message now is default")
```

Which would return something like: **Message goes in red**, message now is default (the bold would represent the color red).

But with logback it's different, it's pattern is set in a xml, I have the following setted up:

```
<pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

Which returns: `702 [run-main-0] WARN className MESSAGE`

As anyone can guess, it won't accept `Console.RED` for changing the color. I know that `\u001B[31m` it's the equivalent to `Console.RED` but if I change the pattern to:

`%-4relative \u001B[31m[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n`

It will simply return me `702 \u001B[31m[run-main-0] WARN className MESSAGE`

My question is the following, how can I set the xml so the console's output have color on any part of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

See the default Spring logback configuration for a good example.

```
<!-- from org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml -->
<conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
<conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
<conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

<!--  default spring pattern with marker -->
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m %marker %n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
```